# Remove-qadobject bypassing warning message

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete user account from Active directory using "Remove-QADObject"
in a script but its asking for confirmation message below.
Warning!
Are you sure you want to delete this object: 
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):

I have also applied below switches and their results

```
-force = Access denied;
-confirm:$false = No Response;
-warningaction slientlycontinue = no response
```

Answer (score 1):

first result from google lead to : http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/powergui/f/4834/t/19571400

> Posted by andrey moiseev -quest- on 8 Apr 2010 12:26 PM    Use both
>   -Force and -Confirm:$false switches to ensure that objects will be deleted without any questions:
>
> Remove-QADObject  -Force -Confirm:$false

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Remove-ADUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617206.aspx)? It has a `-confirm` switch.

Comment: We are using Dell ARS Service, So we need to use Quest modules to write the script. Can you help me with Remove-QADUser command let